How to scrape with map_dfr without skipping when it breaks from not finding the element of a particular page
I am running a map_dfr on a set of webpages to pull various elements that will be bundled into a data frame. I made a simple example to show the issue with just two pages to loop through. In the first page of the two, there is a "defense" table but there isn't one in the second page of the loop. (There is an offense table for both - FYI)
I was looking up what to do to be able to keep the loop from breaking for any pages that does not include this (or other elements but I just used this one for the example). The Possibly function came up so I have incorporated that in my attempt below. The issue seems to be that the code does create "na" for the defense table that doesn't exist in iteration #2 but when it comes time to add "defense" as a column at the bottom it gives the error included at the bottom of my code. I'm thinking this has something to do with the fact that column is a nested table but am not sure.
My goal is to run this loop by keeping the nested defense table as a column and just have any page that doesn't contain that table to be an "NA" or blank.
DPLYR solution prefered but open to whatever works.
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                     verbose = F,
                     chromever = NULL,
                     port = free_port())


remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

games <- c("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197301140mia.htm",
   "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/196010230was.htm")



remDr <- rs_driver_object$client


test_df <- 
map_dfr(games,
function(game_pull){
  
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
  remDr$navigate(game_pull)
  
  x <- remDr$getPageSource() %>% unlist()
  page <- read_html(x)
  
  szn <- 
    page |> 
    html_elements(xpath = "//*[@class='hoversmooth']") |> 
    html_text2() |> 
    parse_number()
  

  offense <- map_dfr(page,
                     possibly(~
                                page |> 
                                html_elements(xpath = "//*[@id='all_player_offense']") |> 
                                html_table() |> 
                                as.data.frame() |> 
                                janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) |> 
                                janitor::clean_names() |> 
                                nest(),
                              otherwise = "na"
                              
                     ))
  defense <- map_dfr(page,
                     possibly(~
                                page |> 
                                html_elements(xpath = "//*[@id='all_player_defense']") |> 
                                html_table() |> 
                                as.data.frame() |> 
                                janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) |> 
                                janitor::clean_names() |> 
                                nest(),
                              otherwise = "na"
                              
                     ))
  
  
  
  df <- page |> 
    html_elements(xpath = "//table[@class='linescore nohover stats_table no_freeze']") |> 
    html_table() |> 
    as.data.frame() |> 
    setNames(c("trash", "team", 'q1', "q2", "q3", "q4", "final")) |> 
    mutate(offense = offense,
           defense = defense)
  
  df
  
})


Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 2.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `defense = defense`.
Caused by error:
! `defense` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.


Try to isolate the issue. I do not think this is the smallest reproducible example.


purrr::possibly() is excellent for handling errors in such cases, and its default value can be something that's more compatible with our desired output value;
we can extract HTML comments with XPath though comment();
map_dfr() was superseded in purrr 1.0;
usually left_join() would be a bit more robust for combining frames, but apparently it's somewhat tricky to build a reliable lookup table; edited to use bind_cols() instead.


Parsing functions:
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(readr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(janitor, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# hide type_convert() spec message
options(readr.num_columns = 0)

# parse box score tables, return nested tibble, 
# list column name is set by `key`
#   tm                offense
#   <chr> <list<tibble[,18]>>
# 1 PIT              [7 × 18]
# 2 WAS              [8 × 18]  
parse_bxs <- function(table_elem, key = "data"){
  html_table(table_elem, header = FALSE) %>%
    # build column names from 2-row header, magrittr pipe to acess lhs in nested calls  
    set_names(str_c(abbreviate(.[1,], minlength = 3), .[2,], sep = "_")) |>
    clean_names() |>
    filter(!player %in% c("", "Player")) |>
    type_convert(guess_integer = TRUE) |>
    # group_by /nest_by will sort grouping varibles, which can break row alignment
    # when binding columns; but factor order is maintained, so lets turn tm to factor,
    # levels in order of apparence
    mutate(tm = factor(tm, levels=unique(tm))) |>
    nest_by(tm, .key = key)
}

# collect tables from `url_`, bind columns to a single frame
collect_tables <- function(url_){
  html <- read_html(url_)
  
  #>   tm                offense
  #>   <chr> <list<tibble[,18]>>
  #> 1 PIT              [7 × 18]
  #> 2 WAS              [8 × 18]  
  tbl_off <- html |>
    html_element(xpath = "//div[@id='all_player_offense']/div/table") |>
    parse_bxs("offense")
  
  # if not found:
  #> # A tibble: 0 × 2
  #> # ℹ 2 variables: tm <chr>, defence <list>
  tbl_def <- html |>
    html_element(xpath = "//div[@id='all_player_defense']/comment()") |>
    # extract table element from html comments
    html_text() |> minimal_html() |> html_element("table") |>
    possibly(parse_bxs, 
             # let's default to 2x2 NA tibble with correct column names
             otherwise = tibble(tm = c(NA, NA), defence = c(NA, NA))
    )("defence")
  
  #>   team                   q1    q2    q3    q4 final
  #>   <chr>               <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
  #> 1 Pittsburgh Steelers     7     3     7    10    27
  #> 2 Washington Redskins     7     3     7    10    27
  tbl_lscore <- html |> 
    html_element(xpath = "//table[@class='linescore nohover stats_table no_freeze']") |> 
    html_table() |> 
    set_names(c("trash", "team", 'q1', "q2", "q3", "q4", "final")) |> 
    select(-1)
  
  # bind collected tables, keep tm_ columns for now so it would bepossible to verify that 
  # alignment is correct
  bind_cols(tbl_lscore, 
            rename(tbl_off, tm_off = tm), 
            rename(tbl_def, tm_def = tm)
  )
}

Main loop:
games <- c("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197301140mia.htm",
           "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/196010230was.htm",
           "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/198509150was.htm",
           "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202309100atl.htm")

# limit requests to 1/sec
slow_collect <- slowly(collect_tables, rate = rate_delay(1))
games %>% 
  set_names(basename(.)) |>
  map(slow_collect) |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "src")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 11
#>   src      team     q1    q2    q3    q4 final tm_off   offense tm_def   defence
#>   <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>  <list<ti> <fct>  <list<ti>
#> 1 1973011… Miam…     7     7     0     0    14 MIA     [8 × 21] MIA    [11 × 16]
#> 2 1973011… Wash…     0     0     0     7     7 WAS     [7 × 21] WAS    [11 × 16]
#> 3 1960102… Pitt…     7     3     7    10    27 PIT     [7 × 21] <NA>            
#> 4 1960102… Wash…     7     3     7    10    27 WAS     [8 × 21] <NA>            
#> 5 1985091… Hous…     0    10     3     0    13 HOU     [9 × 21] HOU     [5 × 16]
#> 6 1985091… Wash…    13     3     0     0    16 WAS    [10 × 21] WAS     [3 × 16]
#> 7 2023091… Caro…     0     7     3     0    10 CAR     [9 × 21] CAR    [18 × 16]
#> 8 2023091… Atla…     0     7     3    14    24 ATL     [6 × 21] ATL    [21 × 16]



First revision with left_join() that proved to be not so robust - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78424112/1

So many new functions in this I haven't used. Can't wait to dig into this and learn more! Hope my Rstudio help function is rested lol. Thanks so much @margusl I'll prob have some questions soon!

I'm slowly starting to figure out some of what you did - for now though, I'm noticing the offense and defense tables are not pulling for a particular team in another game log that wasn't included in my example: 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/198509150was.htm'. I tried other Houston Oilers games and same thing happened. It will pull the other team. Why might that be the case? @margusl

I figured it out (havent fixed it yet but figured it out). When teams change their names across years, the created "tm" column is different thus ruining the join on "tm" at the end.

@JeffHenderson, nice catch!  I edited my answer to use dplyr::bind_cols() instead, it also keeps team names for box tables, so it would be possible to check if rows are correctly aligned, though it shouldn't be an issue. Feel free to leave a comment if you find some pieces somewhat puzzling.

Getting closer @margusl Cpl things I'm noticing. One I fixed. That being there are some games that go to overtime so an additional column is in the tbl_lscore. I fixed it with an if else statement that worked perfectly. But, I think (not 100% sure) the nest_by() function is aphabetizing the rows based on the team name. In all three examples, the first row just so happens to be prealphabetized so there isn't an issue but if you add the following url to our games set you should see the issue: "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202309100atl.htm".

For example, Desmond Ridder is the first name in the nested offense col with Carolina as the team. He actually plays on Atlanta and Bryce Young (first name in offense for Atlanta) actually plays for Carolina

Solved it! Probably not as elegant but it works. Added to parse_bxs function - mutate(tm_num = ifelse(tm == lag(tm), 0, 1),
tm_num = ifelse(is.na(tm_num), 0, tm_num),
tm_num = cumsum(tm_num)) |>
#change order
mutate(tm_num = ifelse(tm_num == 1, 0, 1)) |>
mutate(tm = forcats::fct_reorder(tm, -tm_num)) |>
nest_by(tm, .key = "data")

BTW Do you have a way I can send you a tip for being so helpful? Also if you're open to tutoring, I'm super eager to get better at webscraping in R and feel I'd learn a lot if that's something you're open to on any level. Thanks again either way!

Oh.. you are right, grouping variables are sorted. Some discussion about it can be found here for group_by + summarise, but it applies to nest_by as well. I made another edit,  order should now be fixed by mutate(tm = factor(tm, levels=unique(tm))) in parse_bxs()  as factor level order is preserved. Empty tbl_def  (as in https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/196010230was.htm ) should be covered by possibly(..., otherwise = tibble(tm = c(NA, NA), defence = c(NA, NA)) as it returns 2x2 tibble.

Glad I was correct in my thinking! That's encouraging. Additional question: If I wanted to add the player id which is embedded in html of each players name and add a row to each nested table, how would I do this? Here's the code to pull them for the defence table: html |>
html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="all_player_defense"]/comment()') |>
html_text() |>
minimal_html() |>
html_element("table") |>
html_elements(xpath = ".//a") |>
html_attr('href').

You generally need to build your own table parser to collect & handle html attributes, but in this specific case you might get away with just a frame built from <a> elements that would hold name - href pairs, which can later be joined to other frames. Though no telling without testing. And I'm afraid it also starts to fall out of the scope of this topic, so perhaps it's time to open a follow-up question.

Thanks. I was able to figure it out perhaps inefficiently but effectively with not even making any parsing functions. Really appreciate your help - once more if you are open to doing some tutoring I'm looking for someone like you that could help me get better at scraping in R. Let me know! One thing I dont understand from your code is why we end the possibly function with "("defence")" or whatever else we want to name it.

possibly()takes function as an input, modifies it and returns another functions, so("defence")at the end is for calling that modified functions. It can get bit confusing when used in pipelines, buttbl_def <- ... |> html_element(...) |> possibly(parse_bxs, otherwise = tibble(...))("defence")could be rewritten as: table_element <- html_element(...); parse_bxs_p <- possibly(parse_bxs, otherwise = tibble(...)); tbl_def <- parse_bxs_p(table_element, "defence")` .

Regarding tutoring, I'm afraid it would not work out for me right now, but I can recommend former R4DS learning community, now rebranded DSLC, they have nice and quite active slack channel, link available through https://dslc.io/ . I'd also consider https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping to be a must read, along with the rest of R4DS).  And HW recently held a scraping lecture, this should include some topics not covered in R4DS. Slides and materials are available at https://github.com/hadley/web-scraping/

You're the best @margusl I'll look everything you just sent me. I'll tag you in future questions on the event you have availability to respond. Thanks again!

Unfortunately the data on this website seems to just be pretty inconsistently organized. It looks like your main problem is that you're trying to fill in NAs when an error is thrown, but rvest doesn't always throw an error when the data isn't found and sometimes returns NULL instead. If I were to try scraping the site, I might use something more like the below where there's an actual (non-anonymous) function that's defined and can then be applied to each URL.
You also really don't need RSelenium to scrape this site since the data's loaded with the page rather than doing anything fancy with Javascript behind the scenes so I've removed that to isolate the issue itself.
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

getGameData <- function(url){
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  szn <- page |> 
    html_elements(xpath = "//*[@class='hoversmooth']/li[2]") |> 
    html_text2() |> 
    readr::parse_number()
  
  game_data <- page %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//table[@class='linescore nohover stats_table no_freeze']") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("trash", "team", 'q1', "q2", "q3", "q4", "final")) %>%
    select(team:final)
  
  offense_elem <- html_element(page, xpath = "//*[@id='all_player_offense']")
  if(is(offense_elem, "xml_node")){
    offense_data <- html_table(offense_elem, header = FALSE) %>%
      filter(X3!="Passing") %>%
      filter(X1!="Player") %>%
      setNames(c("Player", "Tm", "Cmp", "Att", "Yds", "TD", "Int", "Sk", "Yds", 
                 "Lng", "Rate", "Att", "Yds", "TD", "Lng", "Rec", "Yds", "TD", 
                 "Lng")) %>%
      split(.$Tm)
  } else {
    offense_data <- list(NA, NA)
  }
  game_data$offense <- offense_data
  
  defense_elem <- html_element(page, xpath = "//*[@id='all_player_defense']")
  if(is(defense_elem, "xml_node")){
    defense_table <- html_table(defense_elem, header = FALSE)
    if(nrow(defense_table)>0){
      defense_data <- defense_table %>%
        filter(X3!="Passing") %>%
        filter(X1!="Player") %>%
        setNames(c("Player", "Tm", "Cmp", "Att", "Yds", "TD", "Int", "Sk", "Yds", 
                   "Lng", "Rate", "Att", "Yds", "TD", "Lng", "Rec", "Yds", "TD", 
                   "Lng")) %>%
        split(.$Tm)
    } else {
      defense_data <- list(NA, NA)
    }
  } else {
    defense_data <- list(NA, NA)
  }
  game_data$defense <- defense_data
  return(game_data)
}

games <- c("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197301140mia.htm",
           "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/196010230was.htm")
all_game_data <- lapply(games, getGameData) %>%
  bind_rows()

With the full function, we're able to define better error handling logic for when the node doesn't exist (class= "xml_missing" instead of "xml_node") and for when the node exists but returns an empty table.
Unfortunately it looks like both pages you shared were missing an all_player_defense node so I had to guess a little bit about the expected format.

@dubakay I am going to try this hopefully sometime today but before I just want to thank you for putting in the effort here. I was thinking an if else statement might be the solution! Thanks in advance.

So I think Reselenium is needed bc the all_player_defense table is an id but if you inspect the html you'll see it's all in comment form (annoying) which is why I used page inspect to do so. Still - I'm going to adapt this to my rselen code and see what happnes.

My understanding of the commented code was that it was just a placeholder for the actual values that would be there if so, but I didn't do the full inspection necessary to figure that out so lmk if it's incorrect!

Hi @dubukay so even for the page that has a defense stats table, html_element is not identifying the xml node. When I run your function across both iterations, it works, but gives NA for defense stats even for the first page that clearly has that table. You can inspect the html on a browser and see it has an id "player_defense". But read_html(page, xpath = "//*[@id='player_defense']" returns nothing.

You run the same thing with player_offense and it does pick it up. I don't understand why it's not identifying that node for the defense table but I feel like it has something to do with the fact that right about it on the html page it looks like the defense table exists as a comment (offense doesn't).
