Webscraping Pro Football Reference
I am trying to webscrape the Defence Table from the following page: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202402110kan.htm
Note there are multiple tables on this page so you need to scroll down a bit to see the defence table
I have used the following code
url <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202402110kan.htm"
table_defence <- url %>% read_html %>%  
          html_node('#div_all_player_defense') %>% 
      html_table()

However I get the following error
Error in UseMethod("html_table") :
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
Based on the URL I am not sure if this issue is because the URL has HTM rather than HTML?
I have tried using rvest but open to use another solution if that works.

The Defense table is collapsed, you need to find the frame containing it from your browser, or use the RSelenenium package.

I still get the same error when I add the () to read_html

url <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202402110kan.htm"
table_defence <- url %>% read_html() %>%


html_node('#div_all_player_defense') %>%
html_table()
Error in UseMethod("html_table") :
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"


That selector should read div#all_player_defense or just #all_player_defense.  But your main issue here is mixing javascript-renedered dom tree (what you'd see in inspetor in broser's dev tool if javascript is not disabled) and page source ( available though read_html() ). Not an exact duplicate, but includes an example for extracting that very same table from pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/ - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78420621/646761 .

library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202402110kan.htm"

# Ingest HTML from URL and convert to string.
html <- as.character(read_html(url))

# Use regular expressions to remove comments
cleaned <- str_remove_all(html, "(<!--|-->)")

# Ingest HTML from string.
html <- read_html(cleaned)

html %>%
  html_nodes("div.table_container")

defense <- html %>%
  html_node("#player_defense") %>%
  html_table()

# Transfer first row (actually second <th> row) to column names.
colnames(defense) <- defense[1,]
# Drop first row.
defense <- defense[-1,]

defense

The results look like this:
   Player            Tm    Int   Yds   TD    Lng   PD    Sk    Comb  Solo  Ast   TFL   QBHits FR    Yds   TD    FF   
   <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 Ji'Ayir Brown     SFO   1     0     0     0     1     0.0   11    7     4     0     0      0     0     0     0    
 2 Arik Armstead     SFO   0     0     0     0     0     1.0   6     3     3     1     1      0     0     0     0    
 3 Javon Hargrave    SFO   0     0     0     0     0     1.0   6     3     3     1     1      1     0     0     0    
 4 Chase Young       SFO   0     0     0     0     0     1.0   2     1     1     1     2      0     0     0     0    
 5 Fred Warner       SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   13    9     4     0     0      0     0     0     0    
 6 Deommodore Lenoir SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   8     4     4     0     0      0     0     0     1    
 7 Logan Ryan        SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   7     3     4     0     0      0     0     0     1    
 8 Nick Bosa         SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   6     4     2     2     3      0     0     0     0    
 9 Oren Burks        SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   5     3     2     0     0      0     0     0     0    
10 Tashaun Gipson    SFO   0     0     0     0     0     0.0   5     4     1     0     0      0     0     0     0 

